# Javascript remove element by an Array by index

Tags: javascript

I have an Array as
arr =["Apple","Banana","Mango","Banana","Goa","Banana"]
These are having Index position as ,0,1,2
if i want to remove Banana Which is having  Index as 0 (Zero) how can i remove that particular element.

Comment: [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) it off.

Answer (score 1):

just check out this example. you just need to splice as here I am using array

```js
const array = [2, 5, 9];

console.log(array);

const index = array.indexOf(5);
if (index > -1) {
  array.splice(index, 1);
}
document.getElementById("dem").innerHTML = array;
```

```html
<div id="dem">Hi </div>
```

ample

```
const array = [2, 5, 9];

console.log(array);

const index = array.indexOf(5);
if (index > -1) {
  array.splice(index, 1);
}

// array = [2, 9]
console.log(array);
```

Comment: i dont want to introduce an element name. i will pass only Index

Comment: sorry but JavaScript is not as simple as python.